# How to compile a java file from atom-editor

Tags: atom-editor

I have a java file open in atom-editor.
I have added both java and GitHub.exe to my path.

My path looks like this ...

`C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;C:\Users\stevenmark\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\JZT72PK5.8TP\Y0KNAOLR.7XA\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0003.0003_5794af8169eeff14\GitHub.exe`

I can run both GitHub and javac from the command line so I know that the path is correct. ( and I can compile this file from the command line )

So I open the java file in atom and then do the key combo ctrl+shift+B and I get the following error appear at the bottom of the screen

`javac: invalid flag: 'test.java'
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
[Finished in 0.355s]`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The output looks a lot like Sublime Text's built tools. Which package do you use to build in Atom?

Comment: I am using 'Script'.
https://atom.io/packages/script

Comment: You know that the `PATH` is right because the error you get is from `javac`. The trouble is that the error suggests that the name of the file was passed in as a flag, and I'm not sure how that would happen from looking at the code of the package: https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/blob/master/lib/grammars/java.coffee#L20 Would you be open for an answer that involves using a different package?